# Regression model to predict student's grade in R

Tags: r

Please I need your help!

I have data for 2017 with the folowing variables:

**Age**:*Numeric*

**Gender**:*Gender Value M=Male, F=Female, X=Indeterminate/Intersex/Unspecified*

**Postal Postcode**:*Numeric Code*

**Residential postcode**: *1 = Major Cities, 2 = Inner Regional,3 = Outer Regional, 4 = Remote and 5 = Very Remote* 
Socio-Economic: *0-99 where 0 is low Socio-Economic and 99 is high *

**School Code**: Numeric Code

**Educational attainment of first parent**:*Numeric*

**Educational attainment of second parent**:*Numeric*

**Grade**:*Numeric  between 0 and 100*

I would like to training on 2017 data to predict student's grade in 2018 (for example, if we have a student got grade 80 and in 2018 we have a student with the same variables or very similar so the predicted grade should something close to 80)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Thank you, vitalious! I have used your script and I got the results!
Here’s the script I used and the data:

```
data<-read.csv("Olddata.csv")
newdata<-read.csv("Newdata.csv")

model <- lm(Age~., data=data)
nextYear <- data
nextYear$Age <- nextYear$Age + 1
results <- predict(model, newdata=nextYear, type='response')
```

Assume that we have only the following variables:

Age Gender  Postal.Postcode  Grade
20  F   3191    89.6
20  M   3930    99
20  F   3126    99.2
21  M   3910    94.65

And the newdata could be anything with the same number of variables.

The output was something like:
1        2        3        4
20.09547 20.48317 19.82224 20.55038

But actually, the output I want is the actual grade for each student out of 100!

Comment: We can't help you "urgently" without data or code or even a sense of how you're trying to do this

Comment: Thank you Camille! The data has 8 variables and no idea how to do the prediction

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/15-types-of-regression-you-should-know or indeed https://www.dataquest.io/blog/statistical-learning-for-predictive-modeling-r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a linear regression model.
In R, it's invoked with `lm()`. You can read more [here](http://r-statistics.co/Linear-Regression.html).
You'd want to fit a model predicting the grade, and then run the model on the data with the Age incremented by one, since presumably, that is the only attribute that will be changing next year.

Assuming your data is in a dataframe called data, it would look something like this:

```
model <- lm(Age~., data=data)

nextYear <- data
nextYear$Age <- nextYear$Age + 1
results <- predict(model, newdata=nextYear, type='response')
```

Make sure that all non-numeric columns are factors.

Comment: Why would this be logistic? The OP is trying to predict a numeric grade, at least as far as I can tell from the description

Comment: Thank you, Vitalious and Camille! Vitalious, can you please update the script please?

Comment: Thank you very much Vitalious! I have replayed to your soution by modifed the question. Could you please have a look and let me know?

Comment: Done and the results are: The output was something like: 1 2 3 4
20.09547 20.48317 19.82224 20.55038

But actually, the output I want is the actual grade for each student out of 100!

Comment: @user10672282 Glad it worked for you! Please upvote my answer as well :)